# SQL nullable bit in where clause

Tags: t-sql

```
create procedure [dbo].[MySproc]
@Value bit = null
as

select columna from tablea where columnb = @Value
```

This does not work if I pass in null to the parameter. Obviously when I change the predicate to columnb is null it works.

What can I do to get this to work without using conditional logic (if/else)?

Update: I figured it out based on @gbn answer

```
where (@Value is null and columnb is null) or (columnb = @Value)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming you want true if 1=1, 0=0 or NULL=NULL

```
select columna from tablea 
where columnb = @Value OR (columnb IS NULL AND @Value IS NULL)
```

What about 0/1 in column, NULL as parameter. Normally, this would be "just give me the rows"

```
where columnb = ISNULL(@Value, columnb)
```

Your logic doesn't make sense because you are using NULL to mean something...

Comment: Right I understand it's causing NULL to mean something and that's why it isn't working. Null != Null. You've given me an idea on how to resolve it though. Thanks.